Read a single char value to stdin without pressing enter on keybard in C in mac os
I am using mac os with xcode-select version 2406
I am trying to find a way to Read a char value to STDIN without pressing enter or return key on keyboard in C.
I know on windows we have getch function but it will only work with Windows compatible machine.
// Windows code
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int a = 0;
  a = getch();
  printf("%c\n", a);
  return 0;
}

Is there is any way to do this task on a unix or mac machine :)

Perhaps use the ncurses library? There are also termcaps which could be used to set the input to unbuffered.
